# C# Update database through foreach loop. ERROR

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, foreach, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is filled with a table from my database. when i make a change to the datagridview and then click the update button i want it to update the database. But i get this error:

> Must declare scaler variable @ShortCompanyMessage

Here is my code for the button press. Is there something stupid i am doing or not doing?lol

```
string dataPath = "myPath";
        string dataFile = "myDataFile";
        string cfgFile;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dataPath + dataFile))
        {
            cfgFile = sr.ReadLine();
        }

        cfgFields = Regex.Split(cfgFile, ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");

        cfgFields[0] = cfgFields[0].Replace("\"", "");
        strDataSource = cfgFields[0];
        strDatabase = "Unity";
        //cfgFields[1];
        strLogin = cfgFields[2];
        strPassword = cfgFields[3];

        string connectionString = "Server=" + strDataSource + ";Database=" + strDatabase + ";User ID=" + strLogin + ";Password=" + strPassword + ";";
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        sqlConnection.Open();

        foreach (var row in GridViewCompanies.Rows)
        {
            var compID = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            var shortMessage = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();         //get value of cells and update there and then? maybe?
            var compMessage = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Unity].[dbo].[Companies] SET shortMessage = @ShortCompanyMessage WHERE compID = @CompanyID", sqlConnection);
            update.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(update);
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You did not pass `@ShortCompanyMessage` and `@CompanyID` to your query

Comment: You need to set sql query parameter values. [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: does that need to go before the =? do i need to replace were i have 'shortMessage = @ShortCompanyMessage' with '@ShortCompanyMessage = shortMessage' and same with the companyID?

Comment: @MOKane, I added my answer below view it might be it help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not pass `@ShortCompanyMessage` and `@CompanyID` to your query so pass these parameters like below

```
foreach (var row in GridViewCompanies.Rows)
{
    var compID = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    var shortMessage = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();         //get value of cells and update there and then? maybe?
    var compMessage = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Unity].[dbo].[Companies] SET shortMessage = @ShortCompanyMessage WHERE compID = @CompanyID", sqlConnection);

    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShortCompanyMessage", shortMessage);   <= Here i added parameter to your command
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyID", compID);                   <= Here i added parameter to your command

    update.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(update);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked a charm. I also had an error in my sql command but i sorted that. Thanks again, much appreciated